# What happens to partition of Kafka topic with replication factor of 1 when a broker goes down?

Tags: apache-kafka

Suppose `default.replication.factor` is set to one. For the sake of simplicity, let's say we have a topic with only one partition. We have a Kafka setup with three brokers. The topic we are interested in lives on the broker that just went down. Obviously, we won't have access to messages on this topic until the broker will be brought back, but my question is what will happen to messages for this topic that will come from producers while the broker is down? Will they be rejected?

Answer (score 1):

The Producer will not be able to locate the primary replica of the partition because there will be no available primary replica because there will be no ISR's (in-sync replicas) at failover time. There will be an error, but I'm not exactly sure it's on the send, especially if you're batching sends.